# 500 Internal Server Error v3 Upload API: GoogleJsonResponseException

Tags: java, youtube-api, google-api

While using Youtube API samples for Java for uploading a file to youtube, I get this:

Error at line: **Video returnedVideo = videoInsert.execute();**

### Error Stack

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 500 Internal Server Error
{
  "code" : 500,
  "message" : null
}
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:145)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:423)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
    at com.omp.util.YoutubeUtil.uploadVideo(YoutubeUtil.java:141)
```

**A related issue is already raised here:** https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=6352

Comment: Could you post a wireshark excerpt of the conversation? Maybe the Youtube API is simply down (as indicated by internal server error)

Comment: Yes, maybe the API was down, however I got it working after a day or two. Marking this as resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved automatically after a day or two! Definitely an API problem.