# APK upload from jenkins failed - language is not associated

Tags: android, jenkins, google-play, jenkins-plugins

I have a Jenkins job configured to upload APK to the Play Market. It produces an error log:

```
Assigning APK(s) to beta release track...

The beta release track will now contain the APK(s): 164

Applying changes to Google Play...

Upload failed: Tried to set recent changes text for APK version 164 for language de-DE.
Language is not associated with the app.

No changes have been applied to the Google Play account

ERROR: Step ‘Upload Android APK to Google Play’ failed: APK upload failed
Finished: FAILURE
```

How this could be fixed?

**UPDATE**: I've added DE to app's languages on Google Play (should this 'associate' language with the app???).

Now Jenkins job gives me this error:

```
Applying changes to Google Play...
Upload failed: org.jenkinsci.plugins.googleplayandroidpublisher.PublisherApiException: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 500 Internal Server Error
{
  "code" : 500,
  "message" : null
}
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.googleplayandroidpublisher.AbstractPublisherTask.call(AbstractPublisherTask.java:36)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1083)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.googleplayandroidpublisher.ApkPublisher.publishApk(ApkPublisher.java:313)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.googleplayandroidpublisher.ApkPublisher.perform(ApkPublisher.java:183)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:78)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:779)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:720)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:185)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:665)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1753)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:404)
Caused by: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 500 Internal Server Error
{
  "code" : 500,
  "message" : null
}
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:145)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:312)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1049)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:410)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.googleplayandroidpublisher.ApkUploadTask.execute(ApkUploadTask.java:146)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.googleplayandroidpublisher.ApkUploadTask.execute(ApkUploadTask.java:35)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.googleplayandroidpublisher.AbstractPublisherTask.call(AbstractPublisherTask.java:33)
    ... 13 more

- No changes have been applied to the Google Play account
ERROR: Step ‘Upload Android APK to Google Play’ failed: APK upload failed
Finished: FAILURE
```

What could help in this case?

Found that similar problem was reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23633189/500-internal-server-error-v3-upload-api-googlejsonresponseexception) and [here](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-33689).

Comment: Upload failed: Tried to set recent changes text for APK version 164 for language de-DE. **Language is not associated with the app**.

Comment: So, how to 'associate language with the app' ?

Answer (score 0):

Some magic has happened and the error #500 has gone, apk is now accepted by the Google Play.